# How to get occurrence of word length? Python3

Tags: python, python-3.x, dictionary, iteration, text-files

Ran into another problem. So I'm trying to make a dictionary where the key would be the word length and the value would be the amount of time a word with that length is read from a text file.

My Code:

```
words = new_text.split()
w_dict = {}
w_list = []

for c in words:
  if len(c) not in w_dict.fromkeys(range(0, 1000)):
  w_dict[len(c)] += 1
else :
  w_dict[len(c)] = 1

w_list = sorted(w_dict.items(), key = lambda x: x[0])

w_final_dict = dict(w_list)

print(w_final_dict)
```

My Output:

```
{1: 1, 2: 1, 4: 1, 5: 1}
```

My Sample text was "hello my name is Kate". Based on that I know that it does iterate and does check if there is a word length that matches the text since there is no word with `len(3)` in output. But there's 2 `len(4)` and and 2 `len(5)` so I don't understand why it didn't increment. Any help would be great. Thanks in advance!

Comment: What's the `w_dict.fromkeys()` supposed to be doing?

Comment: For some reason I get KeyError if I don't include that. The .fromkeys() is supposed to give my dictionary a range of keys and won't return KeyError later on.

Answer (score 1):

I think the problem in your code is this check:

```
if len(c) not in w_dict.fromkeys(range(0, 1000)):
```

You just want to be checking `w_dict`, not the result of `fromkeys` (which I think is a whole new dictionary).

But you can do this whole thing in one line with `collections.Counter`:

```
>>> new_text = "hello my name is kate"
>>> from collections import Counter
>>> Counter(map(len, new_text.split()))
Counter({2: 2, 4: 2, 5: 1})
```

`Counter` takes an iterable for its constructor and it produces a dict where each item from the iterable is a key and the value is the number of times that value appeared.  `map(len, new_text.split())` gives us an iterable of the lengths of all the words in the string, so passing that to `Counter` gives us the dictionary of counts that we want.

Comment: Actually, I spoke too soon, I tried this with another file and this method also included . and other marks - - as a word. Is there a way for Counter to ignore those punctuaion?

Comment: Instead of `len`, use a function that counts only the characters you care about.  Maybe `Counter(sum(c.isalpha() for c in w) for w in new_text.split())`?

Comment: I decided to use another for loop instead that included all the punctuation I didn't need. The file I had to read through had letters with accents and the isalpha function counted them as well so that was a problem. But thanks for the advice!

Answer (score 1):

There is problem with your logic of `if` statement

In Your condition `if len(c) not in w_dict.fromkeys(range(0, 1000)):`

The function `w_dict.fromkeys(range(0, 1000)) generates output as following:

`{0: None, 1: None, 2: None, 3: None, 4: None, 5: None, .... .... 999:None}`

So you can not check using the way you checked with your logic for dictionaries

Hence condition `if len(c) not in w_dict.fromkeys(range(0, 1000)):` will always evaluate to `FALSE` and it will never increase the count and keep overwriting count to `1` by evaluating `else` part

That is why you get output `{1: 1, 2: 1, 4: 1, 5: 1}`

## Correct Solution

Change your condition to this
`if w_dict.get(len(c)):`

`.get(key)` is one of the inbuilt function of dictionaries which returns value based on existence of key. Also it does not generate `KEY ERROR`.

if key exists => Return `value` stored at that key => This makes condition **TURE**

if key does not exists => Returns `None` keyword => This makes condition **FALSE**

So you get desired results

**Remember always - use `.get(key)` function whenever you deal with keys in dictionaries**

Refer to **Dictionaries tutorials** on web to learn more about how to iterate and check conditions on them

Hope this helps and clear your doubts :)

Comment: Yes, it did help and clear up some stuff. However it seems to count . and random - - marks as words as well, is there a way to ignore those punctuations? Thanks

Comment: @code_noob yea u can use `.isalpha()` method of string in `if` condition like this...`if w_dict.get(len(c)) and c.isalpha()`

Answer (score 0):

Keep it simple. Check if the `len(word)` exists as a key in the `dict` and add to the count.

If it does not exist, create the key, value pair.

```
string = 'hello my name is Kate'
data = {}
for word in string.split():
    if len(word) not in data:
        data[len(word)] = 1
    else:
        data[len(word)] += 1
```

Output:

```
>>> data
{5: 1, 2: 2, 4: 2}
```

Comment: Yeah I tried that in the beginning, but it gives me KeyError. Thanks though.

Comment: Unsure on how this would give you a key error. If the key does not exist, it creates it. What is your input?

Comment: my input is a text file, which was open and read. The contexts were "hello there I am Kate"(It's different from the problem above I know, I just noticed that I rewrote it wrong earlier).

Answer (score 0):

The reason you don't see 2 `len(4)` and 2 `len(5)` key values is because python doesn't allow duplicate keys in dictionaries.

Keys in python are used as unique identifiers. By having duplicates you thus create ambiguity. If you try to add a key value pair, but the key already exists, Python will simply update the value of the key in dictionary with the new value.